# Set image to width for only one page without scroll bar HTML

Tags: html, css, image, size

I have a following page:

```
                <div class="Container100" 
                    style="text-align: center; margin-top: 15px;">
                    <img 
                        style="width: auto; max-width: 100%; height: auto; text-align: center;"
</img>
                </div>

                <div class="Container100">
                    <div class="Card ShadowEffect"
                        style="text-align: center;">
                        <div class="ContainerIndent">
                            Text
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The problem is now:
I would like to resize the image to a width that the footer and the image is at one page and there are no scrolling is necessary.
Currently the img is to big and I have to scroll down to get also the footer.
How can I resize the image to the specific width responsive?
I can define a width like 500px but this is not that what I want because the width / height should so big that the image and footer appears at one page without scrolling.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make the image width 100%
along with your page height and width.
also set the float to auto

Comment: you mean <img style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: auto; text-align: center; float: auto" ? I tried this but it doesn´t work

Comment: Try dropping the "style" and putting the style attributes directly in the img tag. If that doesnt work can you please provide all of your code so i can try and solve this for you ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Asign a width and height in % for both the image and footer.

For example:
If image width is 95% of the screen, set width: 95%;
Then set the footer to width: 5%;

That should be it :)